# Convergence to 0 of certain integral by DCT

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral

I need to prove the following property:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}$ a  integrable function  in $B(0,1)$. Then it is satisfied that
> $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{|x|<\varepsilon}f(x)dx=0.$$

My attempt consists in trying to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem. I write
$$\int_{|x|<\varepsilon}f(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}1_{B(0,\varepsilon)}f(x)dx.$$
For $\varepsilon<1$ we can bound $1_{B(0,\varepsilon)}f(x)$  by an integrable function, but I don't have a rigorous proof of the fact that $1_{B(0,\varepsilon)}f(x)\xrightarrow[]{\varepsilon\to0}0$  for each $x$. Sorry if this proof is obvious but I dont't see it in this moment. So, any help will be welcome.

Comment: Hi! It is best to avoid putting MathJax in titles due to [various reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10617/using-mathjax-tex-in-the-titles-of-questions-yes-or-no), including rendering issues in some lists (HNQ etc). I've edited it out of your question for now.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will have in count it for future questions :)

Comment: Better to write $1_{B(0,\epsilon)}(x).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple: suppose that $x_0\neq0$. Then $\|x_0\|>0$. For each $\varepsilon\in(0,\|x_0\|)$ it is $1_{\|x\|<\varepsilon}(x_0)=0$, so for any $x_0\neq0$ it is
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}1_{\|x\|<\varepsilon}(x_0)f(x_0)=0,$$
as this quantity is constantly $0$ eventually.

so $1_{\|y\|<\varepsilon}(x)f(x)\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\to0}0$ almost everywhere, since $\{0\}$ has measure $0$.

As you said, for any $\varepsilon>0$ it is $|1_{\|y\|<\varepsilon}(x)f(x)|\leq|f(x)|\in L^1$ (i.e. your functions are dominated), so you may apply DCT to get your result.